# Como usar Insert com múltiplos registros C# SQL

Tags: c#, sql-insert

Sou novo por aqui e também no mundo da programação, hoje consegui pela 1º vez fazer a conexão do C# ao SQL, ao realizar uma conexão simples com o BD eu consigo inserir registros, mas ao tentar inserir 2 dados na mesma tabela simultaneamente ele cria 2 cadastros ou insere apenas o último, por favor, me ajudem, segue o código abaixo...

```
    private void bt_Cadastrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (bt_Cadastrar.Text == "Salvar")
        {
            tb_ID.Enabled = false;
            bt_Cadastrar.Text = "Cadastrar";
        }

        Int16 Cheque, Convenio;

        if (cb_Cheque.Checked) Cheque = 1;
        else Cheque = 0;
        if (cb_Convenio.Checked) Convenio = 1;
        else Convenio = 0;

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server= localhost; Database=Cadastros; Integrated Security=true"); //Cria a conexão com o Banco de dados devido a Dll que tem na pasta do programa.
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into ccliente (Nome) values ('" + tb_Nome.Text.ToUpper() + "')", conn); //Comando SQL para criar inserir um item em uma tabela existente

        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

        /*
        cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into ccliente (CPF) values ('" + tb_CPF.Text.ToUpper() + "')", conn);
        cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into ccliente (RG) values ('" + tb_RG.Text.ToUpper() + "')", conn);
        cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into ccliente (CEP) values ('" + tb_CEP.Text.ToUpper() + "')", conn);
        cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into ccliente (Cidade) values ('" + tb_Cidade.Text.ToUpper() + "')", conn);
        cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into ccliente (Email) values ('" + tb_Email.Text.ToUpper() + "')", conn);
        cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into ccliente (Telefone1) values ('" + tb_Telefone1.Text.ToUpper() + "')", conn);
        cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into ccliente (Telefone2) values ('" + tb_Telefone2.Text.ToUpper() + "')", conn);
        cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into ccliente (Observacao) values ('" + tb_Observacao.Text.ToUpper() + "')", conn);
        cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into ccliente (Cheque) values ('" + Cheque + "')", conn);
        cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into ccliente (Convenio) values ('" + Convenio + "')", conn);
        */

    }
```

Caso necessário segue abaixo o link para o projeto completo: goo.gl/6P8Hwc (Por favor, se algum moderador achar que isto é errado pode deletar o link, sou novo aqui e não sei as regras ainda).

Comment: Oi amigo, como assim fazer 2 registros simultâneos? recomendo você criar uma classe específica de acesso ao banco, como se fosse uma DAO, e aí, caso queira inserir mais de um registro, passa uma lista e insere um por vez com um foreach, entendeu?

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o seu problema seja na sintaxe do insert, se você realizar todos os cmd que estão comentados, faria um registro para cada linha.. uma solução seria:

```
insert into ccliente TODAS AS PROPRIEDADES values (TODOS OS RESPECTIVOS VALORES)", conn);
```

Mas isso depende da estrutura do seu projeto, por exemplo: você pode ter uma classe [DAO](http://www.macoratti.net/11/10/pp_dao1.htm) (Data Access Object) para cada tabela do seu banco. Em minha jornada de trabalho, quando fazemos uma classe, também fazemos uma classe num contexto de DB, ou seja, a classe que será instanciada e utilizada para transformar os dados que estão na tela em dados pro banco, segue exemplo:

```
  private void bt_Cadastrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cliente novoCliente = new Cliente(); // instância da classe cliente, a qual referencia a tabela ccliente.

        if (bt_Cadastrar.Text == "Salvar")
        {
            tb_ID.Enabled = false;
            bt_Cadastrar.Text = "Cadastrar";
        }

        if (cb_Cheque.Checked) novoCliente.Cheque = true;
        if (cb_Convenio.Checked) novoCliente.Convenio = true;


        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server= localhost; Database=Cadastros; Integrated Security=true"); //Cria a conexão com o Banco de dados devido a Dll que tem na pasta do programa.
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into ccliente values ('" + novoCliente.Nome + "')", conn); //Comando SQL para criar inserir um item em uma tabela existente

        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close(); 
    }
```

PS: nesse meu código falta um ponto importante: atribuir o resto das propriedades na classe.

Outro ponto, quando se utiliza objetos e classes para a comunicação com o banco, acredito que o ideal seja utilizar também [Querys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/query-expression-basics) para realizar ações com o banco, o que torna seu trabalho MUITO mais fácil em conjunto com [LAMBDA](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions).

Enfim, o que eu tentei lhe passar é estude [esse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193542(v=vs.113).aspx) contexto e sua vida ficará muito mais fácil quando o assunto for captura e registro de informações no DB.

Espero ter ajudado :D

Answer (score 0):

Aconselho a estudar mais a sintaxe do SQL. Você pode fazer como M.Bertolazo falou, mas para isso, os campos tem que estar na ordem, e, serem todos os campos da tabela.

A sintaxe correta é:

```
"INSERT INTO TABELA (Nome,CPF,RG,CEP,Cidade,...) VALUES ('Nome','CPF','RG','CEP','Cidade',...);"
```

e aproveitando, a questão, para executar dois comandos, você pode fazer assim:

```
string sql = @"INSERT INTO TABELA1 (CAMPO1,CAMPO2,CAMPO3) VALUES (1,2,3);";
sql += @"INSERT INTO TABELA2 (CAMPOA,CAMPOB,CAMPOC) VALUES ('A','B','C');";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

ou assim:

```
string sql = @"INSERT INTO TABELA1 (CAMPO1,CAMPO2,CAMPO3) VALUES (1,2,3);";
string sql2 = @"INSERT INTO TABELA2 (CAMPOA,CAMPOB,CAMPOC) VALUES ('A','B','C');";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sql2, conn);
conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

há ainda outras formas de fazer, depende muito da sua necessidade.

Leitura recomendada: C# - Trabalhando com parâmetros em consultas SQL
 http://www.macoratti.net/09/07/c_adn_7.htm